# Only return module.exports once npm.load callback is returned

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, require

This is a simplified example of what i'm going through at the moment.

**index.js**

```
var config = require('../config.js');
console.log(config.globalModules); //undefined
```

config.js uses an external package (`npm`) to help populate its `module.exports` object.

**config.js**

```
var npm = require('npm');
var glob = require('glob');

module.exports = {}

// The majority of methods rely on properties which are not set until npm.load has been called.

npm.load(function (er) {
    // now i can use npm properties and methods
    module.exports.globalModules = glob.sync('*', { cwd: npm.globalDir})
    module.exports.localModules  = glob.sync('*', { cwd: npm.dir})
});
```

I have read all the async/sync callback questions on here and have attempted to solve this by using a synchronous package but have failed. I have tried using `sync` and `wait.for` but `var config` is still returning an empty object.

How do i make sure `var config` aka (`module.exports`) is fully populated when `config.js` is required/returned.

Comment: It's not possible. Rethink your module architecture. Hint: do like jQuery ninja mode and have a sort of `.ready()` function for you module. It exports something like `.init(callback)` which allows you to use the module after the async functions complete.

Answer (score 0):

`npm.load` returns long before its callback function, so `module.exports.globalModules` is set *after* you print it with `console.log`.
You can use `setTimeout()` to set some delay for things to complete in time.